# FBConnect: Error "SBJSON.h" file not found

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, fbconnect

I try to add facebook sdk for my app,but has a error "SBJSON.h" file not found.

Target Dependencies,Link Binary with libearies and header search paths has add,
I don't know what happend with it, please give me some advice,thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
header search paths: /Users/alice/Desktop/FBConnect/FBConnect/src

Comment: Can you please show how the file are organized in the finder? Does SBJSON.h placed in an inner folder?

Comment: Do you have header search recursion on? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600782/what-does-it-mean-when-you-check-on-recursive-in-header-search-paths/11601132#11601132